# Tensor products constructed as linear operations by Kronecker products?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensor-products

I know from earlier that [by using Kronecker products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) we can rewrite matrix multiplication as a matrix multiplying a vector:

$${\bf AB} {\bf \equiv \cases{{\bf M_{AL}} \text{vec}({\bf B}) \\ {\bf M_{BR}} \text{vec}({\bf A})}}$$

$\bf M_{AL}$ is the matrix corresponding to *multiplication from left by $\bf A$* and
$\bf M_{BR}$ is the matrix corresponding to *multiplication from right by $\bf B$*

The $\bf M$ matrices can be systematically constructed using Kronecker products of the ${\bf A}$ (or $\bf B$) matrix and ${\bf I}$.

Matrices are 2-tensors - having 2 indexes (row and column). Can one use kronecker products to create tensor products of higher orders?

Comment: Have you tried t do it for a $2\times 2 \times 2$ tensor?

Comment: @draks... :I think I did while writing the question, it was like 6 months ago, but maybe i remember the idea if i think for a bit.